# Cannot execute System.IO.File.Move to a network drive from SharePoint Server 2007 (MOSS)

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, .net

I am using VS2008 C# and MOSS (SharePoint Server 2007).

I have created an asp.net web form which appears on a WebPart within a SharePoint site. When submitting the form, a small .csv file is generated. Ideally I want to have this file created on a network drive (on another server), but for some reason I cannot do this. I can create the file happily on the hard drive of my SharePoint server itself that I am working on, but it just never appears on any network drive that I choose.

I then thought I'd create the file on my c: drive first (as it works), then use asp.net to 'Move' the file to the network directory. I used:

```
System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

This failed also at the 'moving' stage. -  the file gets created fine! On the MOSS server I am working on, there is a C: drive and a D: drive (partitioned). The file creation works fine on both drives, but just not any network drive even if I avoid using drive mappings as below:

(e.g. **"G:\\Group Files\\"** or **"\\\\Global\\Group Files\\"** )

Obviously, I thought security was an issue, so I ensured the MOSS server and the network server both allowed each other with 'Full Access' using Active Directory. I even granted access to myself as a user, admin groups, the ASPNET account, NETWORK SERVICE account (amongst others), etc with MODIFY access. Still no joy. I can PING the network server that I want to create the .csv file on, so it is 'seeing' it.

The work-around that I have done is create the file on the SharePoint server's c: drive, then run a batch file (on schedule) that purely copies the file to the destination G: drive - this works a treat, but I am frustrated that I cannot create the file on the destination server straight away, using code.

I've got a hunch it is SharePoint related, but if anyone can shed light on this matter I'd be extremely grateful!!

Thanks in advance, Ash ;-)

Comment: It does sound like a security issue.  Does the User ID running your SharePoint app pool in IIS have access to the directories you specify?

Comment: Hi,

Brian, there are no exception messages. 

Steve, to your question, I am not 100% sure. I will find out (on leave at the moment, so will get back as soon as I can).

Thank you both.

Comment: Steve, yes the ID does have access mate.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I had this problem today and found this thread whilst looking for an answer.  My problem was that my temp directory didn't have the right permissions!  Sure, I could get the file uploaded without issue, but I couldn't move it unless I were using a LAN account.  I made sure NETWORK SERVICE and my sharepoint application pool had access, and made sure the user who was uploading the file had permission too.  Then it worked.